# Compare dates - overlooking the hour part

Tags: iphone

I frequently use the NSDate compare method - but I want to consider two dates similar if they are equal in year, month, day. I have made a procesure called "cleanDate" to remove the hour part before I compare.

```
-(NSDate*)cleanDate:(NSDate*)date {
    NSCalendarUnit unitflags;
    NSDateComponents *component;  
    NSCalendar *calendar;
    calendar=[[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]autorelease];
    unitflags=NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    component=[calendar components:unitflags fromDate:date];
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:component]; //Dato uten klokke    
}
```

But my dates come out as:

2011-10-28 22:00:00
and some dates as:
2011-10-28 23:00:00

I want the hour part to be similar, e.g. 00:00.

Whats wrong? Does it have something to do with daylight saving time? Other? Thanks.

Comment: Example: OLD 2011-11-01 13:04:33 +0000
NEW 2011-10-31 23:00:00 +0000
Seem to be the wrong day as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a Time Zone issue... 
I thought NSLog would default to the local time zone - but it seems to default to GMT...

```
Date with GMT time zone is: Sat, 29 Oct 2011 22:00:00 GMT+00:00
Date with system time zone is: Sun, 30 Oct 2011 00:00:00 GMT+02:00
NSlog shows 2011-10-29 22:00:00 +0000

When using NSLog(@"NSlog shows %@",finalDate); it seems to print the GMT time... 
When using this code - I will get the local date in my time zone:

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"Date with system time zone is: %@",dateString);
```

... so my original cleanDate actually seems to do what I want after all...

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSDate*)cleanDate:(NSDate*)date {

            NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                                           components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit 
                                           fromDate:date];
                [comps setHour:0];
                [comps setMinute:0];    
                [comps setSecond:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];

            return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. OLD 2011-11-01 13:04:33 +0000. NEW 2011-11-01 01:00:00 +0000. I get the right day... second is ok, minute is ok... hour is 01.... but as long as it stays fixed at 01 its ok... was this as expected?