# How can I ensure all NSDate's in my project have no sub-second components?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

what's the best way to ensure all NSDate's in my project have no sub-second components?

Background - Have got caught out with various dates that are created using "[NSDate date]" at their base, for example then setting hour/minutes etc but no realizing the sub-second component was still there.

What's the easiest way in objective-c to have the effect of NSDate working only to the nearest second?  (e.g. categories, sub-classing NSDate, just manually when creating dates etc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937891/compare-dates-overlooking-the-hour-part/7939091#7939091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDate *roundDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:round([fractionalDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])];
```

You can add an NSDate category to do this in whatever ways you find most convenient.

Comment: thanks Rob - is there a way to kind of transparently "override" the "NSDate date" class method in a fashion that anywhere in your project if you forgot or just type [NSDate date], it will give you the rounded version?  Would this be a category that is made to apply somehow to every class in your project?  (i.e. because otherwise with a category if you forget the import statement your [NSDate date] might refer to the original not the overriden version correct?)

Comment: Internal parts of Cocoa might rely on the normal version of [NSDate date].  Changing it would be a bad idea.